# 404 error in fiddler when loading images in flex

Tags: image, apache-flex, http-status-code-404, fiddler

I've created a component MyImage.mxml in Flex AS3.0 to check whether a file exists or not. If it exists, then we use this path as the source of my image. Otherwise, then we load the "unknownperson" image. The code looks like this:

```
<mx:Image xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.Text;
        import mx.events.DataGridEvent; 

        override public function set source(value:Object):void
        {
                Globals.miniImage = value.toString();
                var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
                _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:Event):void{
                    Globals.miniImage = Intitule.getIntitule('urlPhoto',Globals.languageCode) + "unknownperson_" + Globals.languageCode + ".jpg";
                });
                _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{}); 
                _loader.load(new URLRequest(encodeURI(value.toString()))); 
                super.source = Globals.miniImage;

        }



    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

It works well and it loads the images as it should. However, when I open Fiddler to check all the calls, from time to time there is a 404 error when loading "MyFlexProject/%20"

This happens only when trying to load an image.

Why is trying to go to a "%20" page (that cannot obviously find)? Is there anything I am doing wrong in the load of the images?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing; but it sounds like you're setting the source to am empty string, " " and then it is escaped at some point. I don't believe the problem is with any of the code you've shown; but rather in how this code is used.

Comment: %20 is the URL encoding of a space character. You have an extra space somewhere in your content. Perhaps you should call a string-trimming function on the VALUE object and abort the download if the string is 0-length after trimming?

Comment: thanks, it was exactly that, it is solved now. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*Converted to answer so you can accept it and close the question*

%20 is the URL encoding of a space character.

You must have an extra space somewhere in your content. Perhaps you should call a string-trimming function on the VALUE object and abort the download if the string is 0-length after trimming?